# How can I support a joist length of 9 meters without steel?

Tags: joists

I want to convert my loft and need to span 9 meters unsupported. Can it be achieved without steel beams?

Comment: 9 x ?, how deep?

Comment: Have you looked at "lightweight structural" steel beams?

Comment: Do these need to support a load?  Or is it just for the ceiling?

Answer (score 8):

I just checked some Ontario tables.   For an Attic, not accessible by stairs (i.e. not used as living space,   a 2x12 every 12" can span 32 ft.  But you can't put anything above it.

I've found nothing in the tables that allows a 30 ft span supporting a floor.

While this doesn't mean it can't be done, it means you need to consult with an engineer, and pay for a proper design.

Comment: I think for a span like that you need to look at engineered joists if not an I beam.